# Parse file of group and user names ansible

Tags: ansible

Any idea how to parse this file in order to create users and groups using ansible builtin user module:

**`data/users.yml`**

```yaml
admins: # this is group name
  - rob # this is user name
  - david
  - joy

developers: # this is an other group name
  - tim
  - ray
  - jim
  - mark
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Include the file in its own name:

```yaml
    - name: Include user info from file in their own name
      include_vars:
        file: data/users.yml
        name: my_users

    - name: Show include result
      debug:
        var: my_users
```

Result:

```json
    "my_users": {
        "admins": [
            "rob",
            "david",
            "joy"
        ],
        "developers": [
            "tim",
            "ray",
            "jim",
            "mark"
        ]
    }
```

2. Transform the dict to a list of `group` and `users` dicts to later loop on it

```yaml
    - name: Transform dict to list (demo)
      debug:
        var: my_users | dict2items(key_name='group', value_name='users')
```

Result:

```json
"my_users | dict2items(key_name='group', value_name='users')": [
        {
            "group": "admins",
            "users": [
                "rob",
                "david",
                "joy"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group": "developers",
            "users": [
                "tim",
                "ray",
                "jim",
                "mark"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

3. Use the [`subelements` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html) to loop on groups with a subloop on users. Here is the final test playbook (with intermediate debugs removed for legibility):

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Include user info from file in their own name
      include_vars:
        file: data/users.yml
        name: my_users

    - name: Loop over user info (replace that with user module)
      debug:
        msg: "Creating user {{ item.1 }} in group {{ item.0.group }}"
      loop: "{{ my_users | dict2items(key_name='group', value_name='users') | subelements('users') }}"
```

which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Include user info from file in their own name] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Loop over user info (replace that with user module)] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'group': 'admins', 'users': ['rob', 'david', 'joy']}, 'rob']) => {
    "msg": "Creating user rob in group admins"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'group': 'admins', 'users': ['rob', 'david', 'joy']}, 'david']) => {
    "msg": "Creating user david in group admins"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'group': 'admins', 'users': ['rob', 'david', 'joy']}, 'joy']) => {
    "msg": "Creating user joy in group admins"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'group': 'developers', 'users': ['tim', 'ray', 'jim', 'mark']}, 'tim']) => {
    "msg": "Creating user tim in group developers"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'group': 'developers', 'users': ['tim', 'ray', 'jim', 'mark']}, 'ray']) => {
    "msg": "Creating user ray in group developers"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'group': 'developers', 'users': ['tim', 'ray', 'jim', 'mark']}, 'jim']) => {
    "msg": "Creating user jim in group developers"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'group': 'developers', 'users': ['tim', 'ray', 'jim', 'mark']}, 'mark']) => {
    "msg": "Creating user mark in group developers"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```